# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Tags: shell-script, quoting

I have created a script to export CSV data to mysql table.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /data/NEW
for f in User*
do
        mysql --user="root" --password="user@123" -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '/data/NEW/"$f"' ignore into table new.table2 fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' (table_date, table_name, table_count);"

done
```

But I am getting following errors. But I could not find where I have messed this.

```
test.sh: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
test.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Can someone show me where to improve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to want to include a double quote in your double-quoted command string:

```
"... enclosed by '"' lines ..."
```

You need to escape the embedded double-quote character so that it is included in the string and not terminating it:

```
"... enclosed by '\"' lines ..."
```

Note also that your use of `$f` is totally unquoted here:

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '/data/NEW/"$f"' ignore ..."
```

It would be better to quote it (i.e. let it be quoted by the double-quoted string that it is already part of):

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '/data/NEW/$f' ignore ..."
```

Or, if you need to include the double-quote characters in the command string:

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '/data/NEW/\"$f\"' ignore ..."
```

You may also use a here-document to make the quoting simpler:

```bsh
mysql ... <<END_SQL
LOAD DATA
    LOCAL
    INFILE '/data/NEW/$f' 
    IGNORE
    INTO TABLE new.table2
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (table_date, table_name, table_count);
END_SQL
```

Each quote is literal in the here-document above.

Answer (score 4):

You have a lot of `"` symbols inside your query. You should escape them.

```
mysql --user="root" --password="user@123" -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '/data/NEW/\"$f\"' ...
```

Notice `\"` instead of simple `"`?

It is usually better in such cases to store the SQL script in a file and execute it with redirection:

```
mysql --user="root" --password="user@123" < text_file.sql
```

Comment: I think the file is the best approach +1.